# PhpMyAdmin is exporting varbinary as weird characters instead of HEX

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to backup a MySQL database which has varbinary fields. When I export them, I click the option to export data as HEXADECIMAL, but when I open them in a SQL editor, I have weird characters instead of hexadecimal.

The encoding type is UTF-8!

Example of how it looks in phpMyAdmin:
035956c80365c6257674a62f6c7aa2e0

Example of exported data:
'YVÈeÆ%vt¦/lz¢à'

Comment: Please show an example of the type of characters you are seeing.

Comment: @randak: It's probably just random binary junk.

Comment: How are you opening the exported file?  Your editor might be converting the data into a binary format.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I am opening the file in sublime text edit 2 and the weird characters appear. If I import this into a new MySQL database through php, the data is truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Also had the same issue when exporting tables using phpmyadmin (version: 4.0.10.7) in one of my hosting providers. I had to set up my own phpmyadmin (version: 4.4.11) using the latest version of it from the official site https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/ . It worked. Not gonna provide a real reason why this happens, but I assume is an issue with that specific version.